# Where should I store my App specific config files in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, directory-structure

**Background :** I have some Application Data. i.e. the Database, come important config files.
This data is vital for the application to start else it is exited.

**Problem :** Where should I store this data. i.e in which folder and where. 
Right Now (This is wrong) it is stored in a folder in Debug/App_Data. But is causing issues in git and when we publish the App the data is not found. So where can we store this folder ?

Present Structure is "WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\bin\Debug"

*These Files need to be present when the app is started. So they need to be a part of the app itself.*

Comment: Include those files to your project and set attribute "Copy to Output directory" to "Copy always"

Comment: I will try this. Please add this as an answer

Comment: Not neccessary. Try it first :)

Comment: @AndreyGordeev yours was the correct answer. Please add this as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include those files to your project and set attribute `Copy to Output directory` to `Copy always`

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest use:

```
var pathToConfig = Path.Combine( System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
           Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), YOUR_APP_NAME);
```

On Windows Vista and + machine this will end in "C:\ProgramData\AllUser\YOUR_APP_NAME"

On Windows XP "C:\Document and Settings\Application Data\YOUR_APP_NAME"

in both cases, you guaranteed by OS itself to have write permission in these location, and its "hidden" from the users eyes (both folders are hidden by default)

As @Athari correctly suggests: YOUR_APP_NAME should be YOUR_COMPAMY_NAME\YOUR_APP_NAME

Comment: The recommended way is to use "CompanyName\AppName", not just "AppName". And the folders are "C:\ProgramData" and "C:\Document and Settings\All Users\Application Data", AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your application specific files at

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName));
```

but you can use other folders like `My Documents` too.

Edit: I've remembered I have used Isolated Storage in a WPF app back in .NET 3.0 (I think):

[Introduction to Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[Performing Isolated Storage Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dzkff1s%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Using "Documents" folder is a BAD idea. Because of constant spamming of the folder from all kinds of applications, it became pretty much unusable. Using assembly name is a bad idea too, as the recommended way is to use "CompanyName\AppName". Using assembly name will result in spamming the folder with nonsensical folders. And finally, the original question suggests that data is installation-specific, not user-specific.

Comment: Those points applies to any other folder on the system, too. On "CompanyName\AppName"; I agree. I do it myself; and this answer was just to explain the idea. And - for some scenarios - `My Documents` is a logical place; especially when you intend to reuse and share the generated data - from the user point of view. And for app specific data one could use `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` instead. BTW what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your App.config should be in the normal place for .NET desktop applications: it should be *yourApplication*.exe.config in the same folder as the .exe.